# ¿Cómo agregar leyenda a un gráfico en R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

estoy trabajando en la creación de un gráfico de puntos donde representa el total de casos y muertes por covid a nivel mensual. Pero para que se entienda mejor el gráfico debo agregar una leyenda al lado derecho, en la que salga punto rojo es casos y puntos azules son muertes, nada más. He probado con el comando legend, con scale y no logro ponerlo. Les dejo el código.

```
BasePS2 %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(NúmeroCasos=sum(cases)/100, NúmeroMuertes=sum(deaths)/100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=month, y=NúmeroCasos)) + 
    geom_point(color = "red") + 
    ggtitle("Cientos de contagios y muertes por mes") + 
    labs(y= "Cientos de casos y muertes", x="Mes") + 
    theme_bw() + 
    geom_point (aes(x=month, y=NúmeroMuertes), color = "cornflowerblue") + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,45000))
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma natural de resolver esto en `ggplot` es que el tipo de variable, casos y fallecidos se pueda "mapear" a una estética del gráfico, por ejemplo el color. Esto no puedes hacerlo ahora, por eso estas obligado a usar dos `geom_point()`. Lo que te recomiendo es "ajustar" los datos para que sean más amigables para `ggplot`. El siguiente es un ejemplo, tomando datos parecidos pero de Argentina:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

covid.data <- read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16-bnsDdmmgtSxdWbVMboIHo5FRuz76DBxsz_BbsEVWA/export?format=csv&id=16-bnsDdmmgtSxdWbVMboIHo5FRuz76DBxsz_BbsEVWA&gid=0')

covid.data %>% 
  mutate(fecha = as.Date(fecha, "%d/%m/%Y"),
         month = month(fecha)) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(NúmeroCasos = sum(nue_casosconf_diff)/100, 
            NúmeroMuertes = sum(nue_fallecidos_diff)/100) %>%
  pivot_longer(-month) -> plot_data

  plot_data

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   month name            value
   <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
 1     3 NúmeroCasos     10.6 
 2     3 NúmeroMuertes    0.31
 3     4 NúmeroCasos     33.7 
 4     4 NúmeroMuertes    1.87
 5     5 NúmeroCasos    124.  
 6     5 NúmeroMuertes    3.21
 7     6 NúmeroCasos    477.  
 8     6 NúmeroMuertes    7.68
 9     7 NúmeroCasos   1268.  
10     7 NúmeroMuertes   22.4 
11     8 NúmeroCasos    911.  
12     8 NúmeroMuertes   19.8
```

Se entiende la idea no?, cada fila es una observación de una determina métrica. Dos comentarios más: 1) Te recomiendo que uses nombres de columnas más nemotecnicos, te va a ser más fácil el trabajo, el nombre final de las leyendas se puede ajustar en el gráfico 2) Cuidado con usar solo el mes por período, me parece que esto va para largo y vamos a tener que convivir más de un año con el COVID, por lo que tal vez es mejor hablar de año+mes.

Ahora para graficar es todo más sencillo, solo tenemos que mapear tres dimensiones estéticas, `x`, `y` y `color`, y como consecuencia de esto, solo necesitamos un `geom_point()` y con `scale_color_manual()` ajustamos la leyenda y el color deseado.

```
plot_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=month, y=value, color=name)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    ggtitle("Cientos de contagios y muertes por mes") + 
    labs(y= "Cientos de casos y muertes", x="Mes", color="") + 
    theme_bw() + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1500)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("cornflowerblue", "red"), 
                       labels = c("Casos", "Fallecidos"))
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: me he dado cuenta que "mapee" los colores al revés, el rojo a las muertes (me pareció más lógico), si lo quieres dar vuelta, simplemente invierte el orden en el vector de los colores en `scale_color_manual()`

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en R pero tengo unos buenos apuntes, puedes echar a correr el siguiente script y reciclar lo que te resulte útil

```
library(datasets)

#historigrama
hist(airquality$Ozone)

#scatterplot
with(airquality, plot(Wind,Ozone))

#boxplot
airquality <- transform(airquality, Month = factor(Month))
boxplot(Ozone ~ Month, airquality, xlab = "Month(x)", ylab = "Ozone (ppb)(y)")

# Parametros importantes: 
# -pch: el simbolo del punto (por defecto un círculo)
# -lty: el tipo de línea(por defecto sólida): pueden ser rallitas, puntos...
# -lwd: el grosor de la linea
# -col: el color
colors()
# -xlab: el texto del eje x
# -ylab: el texto del eje y

# Principales funciones
# -plot: Dibuja un scatterplot o de otro tipo, dependiendo de los datos
# -lines: Añade una linea al plot
# -points: Añade puntos al plot
# -text: Añade texto al plot en las coordenadas especificadas
# -tittle: Añade anotaciones a los ejes, título, subtítulo, o fuera del margen
# -mtext: Añade texto a los margenes
# -axis: Añade nuevos ejes

#Ejemplo de varios parametros
with(airquality, plot(Wind, Ozone, main = "Ozono y viento en New York", type = "n"))
with(subset(airquality, Month==5), points(Wind, Ozone, col = "blue"))
with(subset(airquality, Month!=5), points(Wind, Ozone, col = "red"))
legend("topright", pch=1, col=c("blue","red"), legend=c("Mayo", "Otros meses"))

# Linea de regresión - indica la tendencia de los datos
with(airquality, plot(Wind,Ozone,main="Ozono y viento en New York",pch=20))
modelo <- lm(Ozone~Wind,airquality)
abline(modelo,lwd=2)

# Multiples plot - mfrow indica como se distribuyen los graficos
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
with(airquality,{
  plot(Wind,Ozone,main="Ozono y viento")
  plot(Solar.R,Ozone,main="Ozono y radiacion solar")
  plot(Temp,Ozone,main="Ozono y temperatura")
  mtext("Ozono y tiempo atmosferico en New York", outer=TRUE)
})
```

puedes obtener algo más aqui https://github.com/IvoOlivaresGutierrez/r-basics